# Softbox color cast

Tags: white-balance, studio-lighting, food-photography

I have some continuous light softboxes I bought for food photography. Later, I bought another Godox LED softbox to supplement/use as a key light. I still use the old softboxes as fill. The problem now is that the first, cheaper pair of softboxes have a green color cast compared to the Godox. I've tried swapping the flourescent bulbs for LED bulbs in the older softboxes, but it doesn't have much effect, so I'm assuming the problem is the cover. Anyone have ideas on how I could modify the color cast of a softbox cover?

Comment: Are you using the *exact* same type of LED bulbs in both the new and old soft boxes? Just because both types of bulbs are LEDs does not mean they emit the same color balance. They could even be the same brand and still have different model numbers/specifications.

Comment: No, the Godox is a fixed LED and the older softboxes have standard light fixture sockets, so I just tried some standard daylight A19 LED bulbs. Not sure if you can buy LED bulbs with a magenta tint to counteract the greenish cover?

Comment: After searching, I see that you just can buy a large sheet diffuser fabric, so I may have to try replacing the diffuser.

Answer (score 2):

**I.** As you say, "continuous light softboxes" It is most likely you are using fluorescent bulbs inside, that, normally have a green tint and not a good CRI.

**II.** You probably need to clarify (to yourself) if the problem is the covers or the light source (or both).

To do it: Using the same light at the same power, put in front of it one of the white diffusive materials.

Take a picture with a "sun" white balance. Leave the histogram in the middle (the exposition).

Now, change the material and take a second photo. Compare them.

You can do that now by switching light sources and using the same white material on two shots.

**III.** If you find out that the lightbulbs are the problem, you could try finding a socket threaded led light with a good CRI (Over 90-95) that fits inside your softboxes.

**IV.** You can also use a magenta gel to cancel the green tint. But the truth is that it is hard to determine the grade of the magenta tint you need. You could buy the softer magenta gel you can find, and put two layers if needed.

---

**V.** But another option is to forget trying to exactly balance them, and use them in more creative ways, for example adding blue gels and using them on the background to make a teal and blue image, or adding an orange color to make them like a sunset color.

Comment: Thanks Rafael. I agree, I think the cheap LED household bulbs are just too different from the high-quality LED in the Godox light. I'll probably try to find some higher quality CRI A19 bulbs to try next.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the fluorescent bulbs and add a 60 Watt standard incandescent. Fluorescent does not have a continuous spectrum. Adding a tungsten bulb will likely improve the color output.

Comment: I tried LED bulbs in there but the color was still greenish. I'm afraid incandescent bulbs will run too hot...

Comment: Yeap. I would not use incandescent inside a softbox.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest answer is to gel the Godox to a green tint and then use a fluorescent (or custom) WB setting to cancel it out.

If very highly accurate color reproduction is a requirement, then I would suggest you go a different direction and ditch the constant lights (or spend a whole lot more money on LED).

Comment: Thanks Steve, I may try the gel idea. As for LEDs, I thought that the standard household A19 bulbs with a color temp of 5000K would match the Godox... But they are a bit different. I also did an experiment with using a different diffuser, but the color is still different, so it must be the bulbs.

Comment: Most LED's have incomplete color spectrum and a relatively low CRI (color rendering index). Really high quality LED's with a high CRI and consistency are relatively expensive. The ones sold in department stores can be almost anything, regardless of what the packaging says.

Comment: "The ones sold in department stores can be almost anything, regardless of what the packaging says." – The packaging was typeset with a broken keyboard that outputs `9` for most of the digits.